# How to pass payload into java class in Mule 4.3

Tags: java, components, mule-studio, payload, mule4

Is there a way to pass payload into java class in Mule 4.3 ? Can we pass payload as a parameter into a java function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [Java Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/java-module/1.2/) to [invoke a method in a Java class](https://docs.mulesoft.com/java-module/1.2/java-invoke-method). You can use the payload and variables as arguments.

Example (from above docs):

```xml
<java:new class="com.me.TaxCalculator"
    constructor="TaxCalculator()"
    target="taxCalculator"/>


<java:invoke instance="#[vars.taxCalculator]"
  class="com.me.TaxCalculator"
  method="calculateTax(Double, Integer)"
  target="totalTax">
      <java:args>#[{
        price: 25.5,
        percentAdditionalTax: 2
      }]</java:args>
</java:invoke>
```